# Adding Aladdin eToken certificate to keychain on MacOSX

Tags: macos, vpn, e-token

I Have an Aladdin eToken with certificate on it. On Win Xp there is no any problem of using this certificate with cisco VPN. Now I want to add a certificate to the keychain on my mac. I found the following command:

`sc_auth accept [-u user] -h hash`

But I have no idea how to get a hash from eToken. Could anybody provide me a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open terminal and type "sc_auth hash" (with connected etoken and red light on). This will list some apple certificates and the certificate from etoken.

Sample output:

`AA779E7AD6DBB45AFCA48C64F1118E115DFB5604 eToken
B6EFD1C9C5DA0D4B70E18B580BD22757D53D79AA apple..`

Take the hash for the etoken from the list(copy&paste) and type the following 
`sudo sc_auth accept -u username –h hash`

To use etoken for authentication register it with the following commands:

`sudo /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "add rights:system.login.console:mechanisms:0 string builtin:smartcard-sniffer,privileged" /etc/authorization`

`sudo /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "add rules:authenticate:mechanisms:0 string builtin:smartcard-sniffer,privileged" /etc/authorization`

Comment: Please consider expanding this to an actual answer dealing with how to get the hash from the eToken.

Comment: I will, just let me now what shall I do if by typing sc_auth hash there is no my certificate from etoken in the output, only apple certificates?

Comment: What version of safenet(formerly aladdin) pki client software do you use? With version >= 8.1 it should output the hash from the token.

Comment: I'm using eToken pkiclient.4.55.41, this is the only PKI client I can find for my mac. Could you provide me a link for 8.1?

Comment: Try this link: http://www4.fh-swf.de/de/home/studierende/dvz/e_token/der_etoken/downloads/index.php

Comment: Thank you for the link! I've downloaded the safe net client, but every time I try to install it getting the same error from the screenshot http://i.stack.imgur.com/kQ8mZ.png . Don't no exactly what is it, I've already tried to delete all of the aladdin temporary files, plist-files, redownload it, still the same

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall pkiclient 4.55.41 first? I would try to uninstall all files from ealier installations first and then rertry installation of version 8.1

Comment: After several restarts it appeared in application menu, strange, but anyway good. Now my token appears in `sc_auth hash` and I did all of the steps you mentioned above, thank you. Now I can see certificate in keychain, but still in my vpn connection it doesn't show up when I click select certificate.

Comment: sorry, but i can't get vpn to work at this time too. i have the same strange behavior, my certificate does not appear in the keychain section for vpn connections.